# Why am I getting this error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when trying to fetch data from an api?

Tags: python, json, api, typeerror

```
json file = 
    {
      "success": true,
      "terms": "https://curr
      "privacy": "https://cu
      "timestamp": 162764598
      "source": "USD",
      "quotes": {
        "USDIMP": 0.722761,
        "USDINR": 74.398905,
        "USDIQD": 1458.90221
       
      }
    }
```

### The json file is above. i deleted lot of values from the json as it took too many spaces. My python code is in below.

```py
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
    
    import json
    
    response = "http://api.currencylayer.com/live?access_key="
    
    api_key = "42141e*********************"
    parms = dict()
    
    
    
    parms['key'] = api_key
    url = response + urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)
    mh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)    
    source = mh.read().decode()
    
    data = json.loads(source)
    pydata = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
    
    print("which curreny do you want to convert USD to?")
    xm = input('>')
    print(f"Hoe many USD do you want to convert{xm}to")
    value = input('>')
    
    fetch = pydata["quotes"][0]["USD{xm}"]
    
    answer = fetch*value 
    
    print(fetch)
--------------------------------
```

Here is the
output
"fetch = pydata["quotes"][0]["USD{xm}"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: ```"USD{xm}"``` cannot be termed as an index for list indexing. What you are doing is usually done for dictionaries. To get a value of  list, only integers are required

Comment: Based on your sample data, pydata['quotes'] refers to a dictionary (not an array) with keys of 'USDIMP', 'USDINR' & 'USDIQD'. Therefore you'll need something like pydata['quotes']['USDINR']

Comment: @Sujay There is no list in the sample JSON

Comment: @Sujay fetch = pydata["quotes"]["USDINR"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers ... when i added INR directely also the same error

Comment: @Sujay when i directly try to fetch it from python dictionary , this is the error     fetch = data["quotes"][0]["USDINR"]        
KeyError: 'quotes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the JSON data you posted here is not valid. There are missing quotes and commas. For example here `"terms": "https://curr`. It has to be `"terms": "https://curr",`. The same at `"privacy"` and the `"timestamp"` is missing a comma.
 After i fixed the JSON data I found a solution. You have to use `data` not `pydata`. This mean you have to change `fetch = pydata["quotes"][0]["USD{xm}"]` to `fetch = data["quotes"][0]["USD{xm}"]`. But this would result in the next error, which would be a KeyError, because in the JSON data you provided us there is no array after the `"qoutes"` key. So you have to get rid of this `[0]` or the json data has to like this:

```
"quotes":[{
    "USDIMP": 0.722761,
    "USDINR": 74.398905,
    "USDIQD": 1458.90221
   }]
```

At the end you only have to change `data["quotes"]["USD{xm}"]` to `data["quotes"]["USD"+xm]` because python tries to find a key called `USD{xm}` and not for example `USDIMP`, when you type "IMP" in the input.
I hope this fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Felix, yes it worked. This is my first python project, and you helped me complete it. Once again, thanks a lot.